# Count of column from joined table but include zeroes (can't get LEFT JOIN to work)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, left-join

I have to tables. One with Users (called `Actor`) and one with Orders (called `Ord`).

Each order can be assigned to one user, but not all orders have users assigned.

I want to make a select statement that returns all my users and show how many orders are assigned to each one. Including those users that have no orders assigned.

Pretty simple, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT Usr, COUNT(Ord.OrdNo)
FROM Actor
    LEFT JOIN Ord on Actor.EmpNo = Ord.Rsp
WHERE Actor.Gr2 <> 9
    AND Actor.R1 = 10
    AND Ord.OrdTp = 6
    AND Ord.OrdPrSt2 != 0x10
GROUP BY Actor.Usr
```

This just returns the users that have orders assigned to them, but I want all users returned, just with a zero if they have no orders assigned.

Please disregard the `WHERE` clauses (I havent't included the columns/values in the sample data below). Despite these I should still get around 10 users returned when running the query on my live data.

**Sample data**

Table: Actor

```
Usr      EmpNo
----------------
ben      123
jane     124
jack     125
tom      126
```

Table: Orders

```
OrdNo    Rsp
----------------
555551   123
555552   123
555553   124
555554   126
```

This is what I want returned:

```
Usr      Count
----------------
123      2
124      1
125      0
126      1
```

But instead I get this:

```
Usr      Count
----------------
123      2
124      1
126      1
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: Just use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `Left JOIN`

Comment: @HasanGholamali, same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the Ord conditions from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true `LEFT JOIN` result:

```
SELECT Usr, COUNT(Ord.OrdNo)
FROM Actor
    LEFT JOIN Ord on Actor.EmpNo = Ord.Rsp
        AND Ord.OrdTp = 6
        AND Ord.OrdPrSt2 != 0x10
WHERE Actor.Gr2 <> 9
    AND Actor.R1 = 10
GROUP BY Actor.Usr
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

without the where condition i am getting the desired results. here is the code i ran:

[image]

select  a.empno,
    count(ordrno)
    from  actor a left join orders b 
    on a.empno = b.rsp
    group by a.empno